# 【Rails】I do not be able to create or update some tables that have relations like parent, child and grand-child from same one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can not create record such as parent, child and grand-child tables. when I click button that has new method on parent controller. then I catch this issue as below.

NoMethodError in ClassController#new
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

I check some articles they describe same points that I have to fix controller and 3 model files that parent, child and grand-child. I tried my code as below.

```
## controller
classes_controller.rb

  def new
    @class = Class.new
    teacher = @class.build_teacher
    teacher.students.build
  end

## model
class.rb

  has_one :teacher, inverse_of: :class
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher

teacher.rb

  belongs_to :class, inverse_of: :teacher

  has_many :students, inverse_of: :teacher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students

student.rb

  belongs_to :teacher, inverse_of: :students
```

NoMethodError in ClassController#new
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from trying to use Class as your model name.

The class `Class` already exists!  It is the built in Ruby class that all new classes subclass from by default.  And calling `Class.new` is actually creating a new Ruby class, not an instance of an ActiveRecord model as you’re intending.

[Ruby docs for Class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html)

The solution here is simply to rename your model.